# Jquery autocomplete change source

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have **[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7RL4p/5/)**

And I need availabletags1 as source if it's choice1 radio button is chosen and availabletags2 if choice2 radio button is chosen. 
And I need to change this dynamically by actual user choice.

**CODE:**

```
 var availableTags1 = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp"
];

var availableTags2 = [
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];

$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags1
});

$('input[name="choice"]').click(function(){
if(this.checked){
    if(this.value == "1"){
        $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete('option', 'source', availableTags1)
    } else {
        $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete('option', 'source', availableTags2)
    }
```

Comment: are `availabletags1 ` and `availabletags2` arrays

Comment: also what is `choice1 ` and `choice2`

Comment: Sry, I post wrong link on jsfiddle, now it should be ok.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try

```
$('input[name="choice"]').click(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        if(this.value == "1"){
            $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete('option', 'source', availableTags1)
        } else {
            $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete('option', 'source', availableTags2)
        }
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rcSZY/)

Comment: Great, it works. Now I just need to merge your solution with this [http://jsfiddle.net/7RL4p/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/7RL4p/11/) and I still can't get it work.

Comment: Amazing, thanks. Do you know how to add search by "typed letter" - i mean - if user type "c" now (from availableTags1) - it shows javascript, but i want to show nothing, because nothing starts with c. And etc. (if user type (from availableTags1) Sc - it should show Scala, Scheme; if Sca - now only Scala). I hope I wrote it understandable. And also - is somehow posibble to set max number of displayed values? Thanks

Comment: the documentation link about it  : http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-option

Answer (score 23):

For anyone reading this in 2016 and beyond, there is a better way using the `request/response` pattern. jQuery autocomplete has a `source` option which accepts a function which will receive two arguments when invoked by the plugin: `request` and `response`. `request` is an object containing information about the autocomplete component, namely `request.term` which is the value of the input field. `response` is a function, accepting a single parameter, the returned data `response(data)`. as you can see in my example below, you can use this option to facilitate an ajax request. you can simply pass the `request` function as the success callback to jQuery `$.ajax` methods and it will work as intended. you could also do other cool stuff using this pattern, like searching in memory if you have already fetched and cached some data, making subsequent searches more real time for users.

```
$('#term-search').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $('#api-endpoint').val(),//whether you are using radios, checkboxes, or selects, you can change the endpoint at runtime automatically
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                query : request.term,//the value of the input is here
                language : $('#lang-type').val(), //you can even add extra parameters
                token : $('#csrf_token').val()
            },
            success: response //response is a callable accepting data parameter. no reason to wrap in anonymous function.
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    cacheLength: 0,
    select: function(event, ui) {} //do something with the selected option. refer to jquery ui autocomplete docs for more info
});
```

Comment: That's awesome !

Answer (score 0):

In my case i wanted to change the source data inside `source` function and mutate them before the responce(). So i just put a global variable (to the global execution context) in order to change the value of the global var in second time...

Example:

```
....

var jsonData = null;

....

// maybe inside a listener the code below
if (cond1) {
    jsonData = ['item1','item2'];
else {
    jsonData = ['anotherItem1', 'anotherItem2'];
}

....

$("#query").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    if (request.term.length > 2) {
      var matches = $.map(jsonData, function(item) {

        // code code code ...
        if (maybeSomeCondition) {
          return item;
        }
      });
      response(matches);
    }
  },
//
```